# Main function and window that supports Opengl 3.0+ and DirectX 10+

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, game-engine, directx-11

I am currently in the process of developing a game engine and would like to support both DirectX and OpenGL but from my knowlegde directX must use WINAPI to open its window but this is a windows only entery point.

Is there any entery point that supports both OpenGL and DirectX and is there a windowing library that is supported by both OpenGL and DirectX.

If there is no easy way to do it can you suggest a good alternitive to this problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to support both? OpenGL is cross platform and will let your game engine work on Windows as well as linux, ios, android etc. Easiest solution seems to be just not using DirectX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windowing system is generally independent of the graphics API. On Windows, the HWND's HDC surface is the target for rendering operations, which is true whether you're using DirectX or OpenGL (or GDI+, etc). To create a DirectX device, you need an HWND, so any cross-platform windowing system where you can get a native handle to a created window should suffice, as long as its message loop is compatible with the graphics API. On Windows to initialize OpenGL with WGL, you will need an HDC (generally obtained from an HWND), so it is really not any different than DirectX.

WxWidgets (https://www.wxwidgets.org/) is a cross-platform windowing system, has built-in support for OpenGL via GLCanvas, and can be fairly easily adapted to use DirectX on a wxPanel by getting its native handle (http://comp.soft-sys.wxwindows.narkive.com/D9t98DQM/direct3d-wxwidgets-do-they-play-nice-together).